# How to build latex documentation with CMake?

Tags: cmake, latex

Situation:

- a small CMake C++ project
- with a `/doc` folder, currently built via a custom `Makefile` in it.

Problems:

- `CMake` and `GNU make` are two separate build systems and it is laughable to use more than one for a small and simple project.
- `make help` does not list a `doc` target

Tried solutions:
Googled the problem, got suggested to use `add_custom_target()`. That sounds like the wrong solution because regenerating the target `.pdf` every time is ... I can't call it "inefficient" as it takes a couple of seconds. But is against C++'s ideal of "pay for only what you use" - yes.

How to generate documentation from `.tex` files given a working `makefile` is already present? With `CMake`.

Comment: maybe something like https://github.com/dokempf/UseLatexMk could help? The advantage of using latexmk is that it will only compile your document if necessary and will automatically do all the auxiliary stuff like creating a bibliography etc.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks bryh; however I had already googled that. Am looking for a more out-of-the-box solution. Although the existence of such suggests none exists.

Comment: The simplest solution would probably just be to use `add_custom_target` to run `make <make command linke options>` from inside the `doc` directory; even though this target runs every time you build it `make` would make sure not to actually rebuild anything. Depending on the size and complexity of the Makefile you may be able to manually translate it; there are no tools that translate a Makefile to `CMakeLists.txt` afaik. You should be able to transform every make rule into a `add_custom_command` in cmake...